# (PHPDesktop) How to get Full path of uploaded file on a controlled Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, phpdesktop

I am developing application with PHPDesktop, one of the features involves uploading file to the app. The drag and drop function is easy to implement, however I need to get the uploaded file full path in order to load other files in the same folder. However the browser won't show the file real path due to security reasons. But as PHPDesktop is running on its own Chromium browser, I think it might be able to bypass the security somehow.

How can I disable such security in order to get the uploaded file (from a drag and drop) real path, given that I have access to the client browser?

Comment: Looked into it. Doesn't seem possible directly unless you modify the behavior of Chromium itself. ..... There are however some indirect solutions that come to mind if that interests you

Comment: @GetSet Yes I am interested in your solutions

Comment: use PHP file manager to choose the file and create your own button to get full path using javascript and HTML and php